# How to truncate db results for assertion using python?

Tags: python

I am getting a .json response and asserting it against database values, however I keep getting an error during assertion in my tests. What's the best approach? 
My error:

```
 db_results = data_base.fetchall()
        assert len(db_results) == 1
        db_results = db_results[0]
        response = response.json
>       assert response['dealW2Calculations']['pitiPercentage'] == db_results.PITIPercentage
E       AssertionError: assert Decimal('11.762581090909090909090909090') == Decimal('11.76')
E        +  where Decimal('11.76') = (18966, 20506, 1, Decimal('11.76'), Decimal('11.76'), Decimal('17.217126545454545'), Decimal('403000.0000'), Decimal('...02000.0000'), Decimal('107000.0000'), True, False, None, False, F`enter code here`alse, None, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x8f\xb0', None).PITIPercentage
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways really assuming `a = decimal.Decimal("11.762581090909090909090909090")` and `b = decimal.Decimal("11.76")`

1. Round values to a given precision: `assert round(a, 2) == round(b, 2)`.
2. If this is used in `unittest` unit-tests you could use the [`assertAlmostEqual` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual)
3. Use the [`math.isclose` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) if you're using Python 3.5 or later.